# Silveright config error stopped

Tags: silverlight

Server Error in '/' Application.
I have just started to publish the app to IIS server but it is failing, any ideas on this how to solve?

---

Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required    to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. (C:\PBM_Test\web.config line 15)

Source Error:

Line 13:   
Line 14:     
Line 15:  Line 16:     
Line 17:

Source File: C:\PBM_Test\web.config    Line: 15

```
this is the web.config.
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <configuration>
      <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
          <add name="DomainServiceModule" preCondition="managedHandler"         type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHttpModule,  `enter code here`System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
         </modules>
         <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration

    ="false" />
              </system.webServer>
             <system.web>
                <httpModules>
                <add name="DomainServiceModule" type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHttpModule, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
               </httpModules>
                  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
                           <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
              </assemblies>
            </compilation>
          </system.web>
          <connectionStrings>
          <add name="PBMEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ModelPBM.csdl|res://*/ModelPBM.ssdl|res://*/ModelPBM.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=SRVORDERS;initial catalog=PBM;user id=OK;password=OK1;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
          <system.serviceModel>
            <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
          </system.serviceModel>
        </configuration>
```

Comment: Is the reference to System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting marked as `copy local` in the properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see http://forums.silverlight.net/t/180719.aspx/1

and http://community.discountasp.net/showthread.php?t=10296 for info

The above threads describe how you have to make sure that your web application has a copy of this file available.

If you are using a server you can install software to, the best solution is to make sure that the server has both the latest version of .net and RIA services installed (Both may be separate installations) (EDIT - make sure all the packages that alfonso list are installed.)

If you don't have access to install software on the server, the other solution is to make sure that ServiceMode.DomainServices.Hosting 4.0 is copied to the BIN folder during deployment of your ASP solution - set the file properties to Local Copy / Only if Newer

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed all of these packages on the server:

1. Silverlight4 Tools
2. Silverlight SDK
3. RiaServicesToolkit
4. RiaServices

Hope it helps!